# How to convert a byte array recieved from a wcf service to a text file in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

How to convert a byte array recieved from a wcf service to a text file in excel vba?

This is how i am getting the byte array
Dim result As Variant
result = service1.DownloadDocument()

after this code i want to write the code for writing this byte stream to a text file...

Comment: What do you see when you `Debug.Print result`

Comment: i can see a Byte array

Comment: ok, [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd126860.aspx). What are the elements in the Byte Array, do you want to convert them to something else? Also [see this for vb.net](http://www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array-vbnet)

Comment: @Shabeer- it would be easier if you could make a simple example. Perhaps give us a short byte array and the expected result?

Comment: I am just converting a text file into byte stream... string fileName = @"C:\Users\shabeer.t\Desktop\code.txt"; using (FileStream fs=new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read)) { byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length]; fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length); return buffer; } this is my wcf code –

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to convert the byte array to a string, try using the StrConv function, e.g.:

```
Dim myString As String
myString = StrConv(byteData, vbFromUnicode)
```

If this gives you the result you're looking for, write the string to a file using meHow's answer above.